# Nessus ADV180002: Microsoft SQL Server January 2018 Security Update (Meltdown) (Spectre)

Tags: sql-server, meltdown, spectre, nessus

I have a MS Server 2012 r2 running ArcServe 17.5, which uses MSSQL Server Express 2014. When Nessus runs a scan of this system, I am getting the plugin 105613 - ADV180002: Microsoft SQL Server January 2018 Security Update (Meltdown) (Spectre). I have been unsuccessful finding a remedy for this vulnerability, as it continually shows up on the Nessus scan. Any one here have any suggestions? I've already installed every update and patch I can find for this server, for both the OS and SQL.

Mark